# How to do a dotnet install in a deployment group?

Tags: azure-devops, dotnet-cli, mage, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

I'm trying to install and use a [mage tool](https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/tree/master/Documentation/dotnet-mage) in a VM via Azure Deployment Groups. I've already installed .NET 5 SDK and validated that it is installed in the target VM via Command Prompt.

In Azure DevOps. I've tried running `dotnet tool install --global microsoft.dotnet.mage --version 5.0.0` through a Command-Line Task with `C:\Program Files\dotnet` as the Working Directory. It says that the tool is installed successfully. However, whenever I try to run the `dotnet-mage` command it says it does not exist.

Also when I try to remove `C:\Program Files\dotnet` as the working directory in the Command-Line Task, the `dotnet` command becomes an unknown cmdlet.

Then I've tried doing the same steps inside the target VM through cmd and I was successful to install the Mage tool.

What am I doing wrong here? Usually, this works when I'm using a Hosted Agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not set a working directory and it worked on my side. Here are my configurations:

1.Use .NET Core task:[image]
2.Install dotnet-mage:

[image]

3.Use dotnet-mage command:

[image]